# Focusing text through focus manager in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, focus

I have a WPF window that focuses a textbox when the window starts up via the FocusManager, which works. e.g.

```
<Window 
   ...
   FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=nameTextBox}">
```

Upon focus, I'd like to also highlight the text in the textbox. I'd like to do this all in the XAML if possible, as I have no code in code behind and would like to keep it that way.

Comment: This is easier done in the code behind, especially if the text box is bound to some value, since the text to select wouldn't be available at the time the Xaml is processed.

Answer (score 0):

I know you want to keep .cs out of your project but it'll be quite hard to achieve, you can create a one off class with an attached property inside that can be used over and over in your xaml files.

```
  public class AutoFocusBehavior : DependencyObject
{
    public static bool IsAutoFocus(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsAutoFocusProperty);
    }
    public static void SetIsAutoFocus(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsAutoFocusProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsAutoFocusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsAutoFocus", typeof(bool), typeof(AutoFocusBehavior),
            new PropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback((d, de) =>
            {
                if ((bool)de.NewValue)
                {
                    FrameworkElement frameworkElement = (FrameworkElement)d;
                    frameworkElement.Unloaded += frameworkElement_Unloaded;
                    frameworkElement.IsVisibleChanged += new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(frameworkElement_IsVisibleChanged);
                    frameworkElement.IsEnabledChanged += frameworkElement_IsEnabledChanged;
                }
                else
                {
                    FrameworkElement frameworkElement = (FrameworkElement)d;
                    frameworkElement.Unloaded -= frameworkElement_Unloaded;
                    frameworkElement.IsVisibleChanged -= new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(frameworkElement_IsVisibleChanged);
                    frameworkElement.IsEnabledChanged -= frameworkElement_IsEnabledChanged;
                }
            })));
    static void frameworkElement_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement frameworkElement = (FrameworkElement)sender;
        frameworkElement.IsVisibleChanged -= new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(frameworkElement_IsVisibleChanged);
        frameworkElement.IsEnabledChanged -= frameworkElement_IsEnabledChanged;
    }
    static void frameworkElement_IsEnabledChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((bool)e.NewValue))
        {
            if (sender is System.Windows.Controls.TextBox)
            {
                System.Windows.Controls.TextBox textBox = sender as System.Windows.Controls.TextBox;
                if (textBox != null)
                {
                    textBox.SelectAll();
                }
            }

            ((FrameworkElement)sender).Focus();
        }
    }
    static void frameworkElement_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((bool)e.NewValue))
        {
            if (sender is System.Windows.Controls.TextBox)
            {
                System.Windows.Controls.TextBox textBox = sender as System.Windows.Controls.TextBox;
                if (textBox != null)
                {
                    textBox.SelectAll();
                    textBox.Focus();
                }

            }
            ((FrameworkElement)sender).Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Then used in any xaml like this.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="testing" local:AutoFocusBehavior.IsAutoFocus="True" Margin="133,87,292,198"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]